# Phantom tag in close votes review

Tags: bug, tags, review-queues, review-audits

A question in review queue appears to be tagged with a tag it doesn't have.

I have my close votes queue filtered by [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c), [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode). Today a question about Ruby on Rails [appeared](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4888406) in my queue, tagged [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails). This question had nothing in it about iOS. When I opened the question in separate page, it had only RoR tag. I refreshed review page, and [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) was replaced by [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c). I refreshed review page several times, and each time the question was tagged with [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails)  and one of my "filter" tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably an audit. Those are chosen randomly but if you're filtering on tags they're tagged with one you're filtering for.

Comment: Yep it was. I just removed all favorite tags and it appeared, then added some back and it was tagged with it. Did the review and it was an audit. [Image](http://puu.sh/8XQCd.png)

Comment: If that isn't a glaring tell-tale ;-)